# nested image model objects not showing on edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, photo, nested-attributes

I've been ignoring this problem for a while but I can't any longer. My nested image model objects, `product_images` are not showing when I `render` a product's `edit` view. Due to this my application calls an error saying that the image is nil when I try to render the `show` view.

Why arent my nested product images appearing? I'm using paperclip and s3.

I need the nested images form to be editable, everything works when a new product is created, the editing is the only problem. The nil exception during the show action is just related to the edit action malfunction

Below is my code:

### models ##

```
class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id, :photo, :image_width, :image_height
  belongs_to :product
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>"}, :dependent => :destroy

  validates_attachment_presence :photo
  validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
  after_post_process :save_image_dimensions

  def save_image_dimensions
      geo = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(photo.queued_for_write[:original])
      self.image_width = geo.width.to_i
      self.image_height = geo.height.to_i
  end
  def sized_different?
  if image_width < image_height
          true
  else
          false

  end
  end
end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :taxable, :shippable, :page_name, :tact_code, :manu_code, :body_code, :name, :alert, :price, :description, :colors_attributes, :sizes_attributes, :extras_attributes, :restraints_attributes, :product_images_attributes
  validates_presence_of :page_name
  validates_presence_of :price
  validates_presence_of :description
  validates_presence_of :name
  has_many :product_images, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :restraints, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :colors, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :sizes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :extras, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :colors, :sizes, :extras, :restraints, :product_images
end
```

### controller

```
  def index
          @products = Product.search(params)
      unless current_cart.nil?
          @cart = current_cart
      else
          @cart = nil
      end
  end
  def new
          @product = Product.new
          @product.product_images.build
  end
  def create
          @product = Product.new(params[:product])

          if @product.save
                  render :index
          else
                  render :new
          end
  end
def edit
          @product = Product.find(params[:id])
          @cart = current_cart
  end
  def show
          @product = Product.find(params[:id])
          @cart = current_cart
  end
  def update
          @product = Product.find(params[:id])
          if @product.update_attributes!(params[:product])
            render :index
          else
            render :edit
          end  
   end
end
```

### _form view

```
<%= form_for @adminproduct, validate: true, html:{ multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <div class="span3 field">
    <ul class="unstyled">
      <li><%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Product name" %></li>
      <li><%= f.text_field :manu_code, :placeholder => "Manufacturer code" %></li>
      <li><%= f.text_field :alert, :placeholder => "Alert, example: Save 10%" %></li>
      <li><%= f.text_field :price, :placeholder => "Base price"  %></li>
      <li><%= f.text_area :description, :placeholder => "Product description", :size => "30x10" %></li>

</ul>
  </div>
  <div class="span6 offset1">
    <ul class="unstyled">
      <li><%= f.check_box :taxable %>Item can be taxed</li>
      <li><%= f.check_box :shippable%>Item can be standard shipped</li>

      <li><br /><b>Choose product images:</b></li>
      (the first image will be the product's main image)<br/>
      <%= f.fields_for :product_images do |p|%><%= render 'product_image_fields', f: p %><% end %>
            <li><%= link_to_add_fields "Add image", f, :product_images %></li>
```

Any insight is appreciated.

## edit

### product images partial

```
<fieldset>
        <%= f.file_field :photo %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
        <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: If you go to the show page before editing and updating, does it work then?

What does the product_image_fields partial look like?

If you use the console to look at an object you've just created through your form, does it have an image attached properly? what happens to the association when you update the object?

Comment: Try using **Nested Attributes** in Rails

Comment: using nested attributes. The association becomes nil upon update, it works on create. When I'm viewing the edit form there is a bunch of product_image fields but they all say no file chosen

Comment: Are you using CarrierWave?

Answer (score 1):

On the products_controller, modify the edit action to include product_images so that [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) knows which images to update.

```
def edit
  @product = Product.includes(:product_images).find(params[:id])
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call your partial like this:

```
<%= render partial: 'product_image_fields', locals: {f: p} %>
```

If it does not work, please paste in your original question your 'product_image_fields' file and the error message from your console

--

Ok this is your partial

```
<fieldset>
        <%= f.file_field :photo %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
        <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

A your problem is  empty product_image upload inputs. Well you using file_field, which produce `input type=file`, and HTML won't allow you to put a value in this kind of fields. In other words: you cannot load value from a database to a `file_field`.

This is my advise:

Change your partial to output what comes from the database. This is just to verify and confirm the data arrive at the right place

```
<fieldset>
        <%= f.object.send :photo %>

        <%= f.file_field :photo %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
        <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

You should get in the screen the path of your image. Also look at the HTML source, Rails should add hidden fields with your images records id.

If you got all right, then you need to display your image with something else than a `file_field`, try an image_tag or anything else you want to use

Comment: I tried your solution, it did not work. I posted the partial code at the end of my question. There is no error, on edit there is just empty product_image upload inputs.

Comment: if I get rid of the file_field then I can't use this _form partial for both new and edit actions. i want to display thumbnails and also give the option to upload more. The remove link also does not destroy the objects

Comment: I never advised you to get rid of `file_field` ! Read again, see I am suggesting a way to **confirm** the data arrive in your form view. Once you confirmed this I suggest to use a `image_tag`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried you tried using the wonderful `accepts_nested_attributes_for` provided by Rails for working with **Nested Attributes**?

Read more http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

**EDIT**
I thought best to provide you an example rather.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ..., :product_images_attributes # <======= Pay attention here. Mass Assignment attributes required
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images
  ....
end
```

Comment: Are you using CarrierWave?
If yes then you should be using `<%= image_tag f.photo_url %>` or something similar to display the image. Read the Carrierwave gem documents